# Container Nginx Proxy Through Cloudfare Tunnel

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, cloudflare, portainer

I am having some issues and I hope I can get some help. Initially I was trying to run a Nextcloud container through my Cloudflare Tunne, but I kept getting a 502 Bad Gateway error, I read online it's because Cloudflare cannot communicate with the container and they recommended to install a proxy manager, so I am now trying to set up an Nginx Proxy Manager docker instance, but instead of opening the ports on my Firewall, I want to get to it through my Cloudflare Tunnel.

I am able to spin up the Nxinx instance but when I try to set the domain name to redirect to nginx, I am not able to reach it, so I found on Reddit that you need to add this to the cloudflared config.yml.

```
ingress:
  - hostname: xxx.yourdomain.com
    service: https://192.168.1.x:443 #npm
    originRequest:
        noTLSVerify: true
```

I have two issues here, one, I can't find where the config file is natively, and second, when I try to run the container with a --config command or with compose, I get the error that cloudflared can't open the file or folder.

I have tried this command:

```
docker run -d cloudflare/cloudflared:latest tunnel --config /home/"username"/cloudflared/config.yml --name cloudflared --no-autoupdate run --token "my token"
```

And I've tried this docker-compose:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  cloudflared:
    image: cloudflare/cloudflared:latest
    container_name: cloudflared
    restart: unless-stopped
    command: tunnel --config ./config.yml --no-autoupdate run
    environment:
      - TUNNEL_TOKEN="my token"
    volumes:
      - ./data:/home/nonroot/.cloudflared/
```

Any help would be appreciated it, what I am trying to do in the end is: [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com) > hits Cloudflare > sends it to my Nginx through the Tunnel > Nginx sends it to the right container.

And also, does anyone know if I can use Nginx for 3 different Docker hosts, or do I need to do one for each Server VM?

Thank you everyone for your help!